# Telnet - Google Drive GET request error

Tags: macos, http, telnet, google-drive

I'm on Mac OSX trying to use telnet to get a file off of google drive. I found that the following link template causes an automatic download of a file off of google drive:

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?id=documentId&export=download
```

where **documentId** is the id of the document (a combination of numbers and letters). So I go to the terminal, type `telnet drive.google.com 80` and get connected to the server. Then I type `GET /uc?id=documentId&export=download HTTP/1.1`, press enter, type `Host: drive.google.com`, then press enter twice.

I'm pretty sure I followed the steps correctly, but for some reason, I always get a status code of *302 Moved Temporarily*. Did I enter the URL wrong, are there some characters that need to be escaped? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*302 Moved Temporarily* **is not an error** of any kind. It's the HTTP server telling you that the URL is okay but the actual content is at a different location; for example, it might be redirecting you to one of Google's storage servers, or asking to try again over HTTPS.

**Look for a `Location:` header in the response** and issue a second HTTP request for it (after connecting to the apropriate server if needed).

As a better alternative, try `curl -L -o <filename> <url>`.
(Add `-v` if you want to see the HTTP requests in action.)

Comment: is curl an actual command? Because I'm just using telnet to test out the HTTP request which later I'm going to use in a C++ program to download the file off the internet.

Comment: And also, the "new location" link it gives me is this: `/uc?id=documentId&amp;export=download`, which is _the_ _exact_ _same_ _thing_ [!] as the provided link save for the ampersand being replaced by `&amp`

Comment: @rcplusplus: If it has something different, then it's not exactly the same thing, is it?

Comment: @rcplusplus: And yes, `curl` is an actual command, but it also comes with a `libcurl` library for C which is very convenient for downloading files over HTTP, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use HTTPS, do you have some kind of SSL-equipped telnet?

Comment: Tried it your way with openssl, and it worked! Well, it gave me HTML saying "Moved Temporarily" and then had a  `<a></a>` element directing me to the file. All I do is click it and then the file downloads. And that URL is the `Location:` parameter in the response header